# How to write Angular 2 code inside Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, angular

I am a complete novice in Ruby on Rails. Just have learned some CRUD functionalities with RoR.
I am also very new in Angualr 2 and currently learning it.

I have seen RoR has it's own HTML template engine just like Angular.

My question is how can I use my Angular 2 knowledge (very little knowledge indeed) to create front end of RoR application?

I am using Gulp as transpiler for Typescript. Can I use the same in RoR?

**Is there any seed project with Angular 2 and Rails 4** so that I can grab quickly?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Angular CLI. Here's an [Angular/Rails tutorial](https://www.angularonrails.com/getting-started-angular-cli/) I wrote that uses Angular CLI.

If you want to use an Angular 2 seed, there's a [tutorial for that](https://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-2rails-5-app-heroku/) too, but that's not what I usually do.